# EOF error in bash script

Tags: bash

I seem to be having some problems executing this script? not sure what is causing the problem?

```
touch file
cat file | while read line; 
do
output=$(awk '/path/ {print NR, $0}' "$line");
if [$(#output) -ne 0];
then
echo "File: " "$line";
echo "----------------------------------------------------";
echo "$output"
else
echo "No keyword appeared";
fi
done
```

Comment: check on [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: You need spaces around the brackets in the `if [ condition ]` (`[` and `]` need to be parsed as separate tokens, which won't happen if they're next to other characters)

Answer (score 1):

**Based on  shellcheck.net**

Line 5:

```
if [$(#output) -ne 0];
   ^-- SC1035: You need a space after the [ and before the ].
   ^-- SC1009: The mentioned syntax error was in this test expression.
    ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this command expansion. Fix to allow more checks.
```

Line 6:

```
then
    ^-- SC1072: Unexpected keyword/token. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```